# jQuery: Accessing iframe dom from iframe itself

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
$.fn.resizer = function(o){

    var s = {}
    $.extend(s,o);

    return this.each(function(){

        $(this).css({
            'width':s.width+20,
            'height':s.height+20
        })
            .parent().css({
                'width':s.width,
                'height':s.height
            });

    });

}
```

I want to do this with iframe, from inside iframe.

When i'm trying to call it from there via:

```
$(top).uploader_finish({
    width:original_width+<?php echo $this->sizes['width'] ?>+20,
    height:original_height+<?php echo $this->sizes['height'] ?>+80
});
```

Getting window of parent, but how to access iframe directly?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

The only solution i have found, is to calling like that:

$(top.document).find('iframe[name=default_1]');

And default_1 name sending like $_GET parameter inside src of iframe.

Or is there a way to get name of iframe, from inside?

**Update**

AHA! Found it :)

```
window.name
```

So basically it will look like this?

```
$(top.document).find('iframe[name='+window.name+']');
```

Comment: Somebody, you should put your Update as an answer, that way we could do +1 for you. Although, I added quotes around the name. That way it is can work in more cases.

Comment: `$(top.document)` works for me, thx!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the frame by it's ID

```
document.getElementById('frameId')
```

or in the `window.frames` collection

```
$(document).find("iframe").attr("name");
```

Comment: Nvm, how to get a name of iframe from inside? That's all what i need. :)